# Tesseract Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, ocr, tesseract

I have been searching around but can't seem to find a solution to this regarding standalone OCR implementation on Windows Phone.

1) Does **Tesseract** Library work on Windows Phone running on C#?

2) Is there a **Windows Phone OCR app** that runs on **Tesseract** or any other libraries that **doesn't call services over the cloud** to this day?

Answer (score 2):

Only C# for Windows Phone 7, that's it. You can use C++ on Windows Phone 8 though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [modified Tesseract](https://github.com/yoisel/tesseract_winrt) for the WinRT platform (Windows Phone/Windows Store Apps) by @yoisel.